# Can the quantum mechanical current density be imaginary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, complex-numbers

I am dealing with a situation where I get an imaginary transmission current density.

Is this possible?

Does it imply a zero transmission probability?

Comment: The phase of the probability current is underdetermined (unphysical).

Comment: How would you get an imaginary probability current? What's your definition of it? All the definitions of it I know are manifestly real-valued. What is this "situation" you are dealing with? Please give a bit more context when asking a question.

Comment: My solution to the stationary Schrodinger equation is real. Thus, when I computed the current density (an equation that involves $i$) the answer had an $i$ in it. I think this will imply that in my case there is no transmitted particles after the collision with the potential. Thanks.

Comment: I think it'd be best if you included the situation more (what system you're modelling, the wavefunction you've obtained and the probability current).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for the probability current is
$$
\boldsymbol j=\frac{1}{2m}(\psi^*\hat{\boldsymbol p} \psi-\psi\hat{\boldsymbol p}\psi^*) \tag{1}
$$
which is **manifestly real**. As a cross-check, if you write $\psi=R(x)\mathrm e^{iS(x)}$, then the current is given by
$$
\boldsymbol j=\frac{R^2}{m}\nabla S \tag{2}
$$
yet again, a **real** quantity.

Anyway, note that the transmission coefficient is defined as a quotient of currents$^1$, which means that if you get an imaginary current (because you use a different definition rather than $(1)$, which is fine), the quotient will be real, as one would expect. In the end, the global phase of $\boldsymbol j$ is unphysical, as mentioned in the comments.

$^1$: $$T=\frac{j_\text{out}}{j_\text{in}}$$

---

All the formulas are taken from the Wikipedia article [probability current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current).